# Why is the SQLite database not updating inside the jar file?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm encountering an issue with my Java application developed in NetBeans. The application uses an SQLite database, and I've noticed that changes made to the database persist when I run the program from within NetBeans. However, when I build the JAR file and run it separately, the database changes are not reflected.

Here are some key details:

The database file (customerDB.db) is stored in the "databases" folder, and the folder is added as a resource in my NetBeans project.
I'm confident that I'm modifying the correct database file in the "databases" folder.

NetBeans seems to copy the database file to a temporary location during the build process, which is used when running the JAR file.
I would appreciate any insights into why the JAR file's database isn't updating as expected and how I can ensure that changes persist when running the JAR file.

Here's the program for connecting to the SQLite Database, and updating it:

```
public class SQLiteDatabase {

    private Connection con;
    private final String tableName;

    public SQLiteDatabase() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        tableName = "";
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Path dbFile = Files.createTempFile(null, ".db");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:customerDB.db");

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase(String tableName, String tableFields) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        String query = String.format("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s %s", tableName, tableFields);
        
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:customerDB.db");
        
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);
    }

    public void showTables() throws SQLException {
        try (ResultSet rs = con.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, null, null)) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void insertData(int id, String name, String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        String query = String.format("INSERT INTO %s VALUES(?,?,?,?)", tableName);
        PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(query);
        p.setInt(1, id);
        p.setString(2, name);
        p.setString(3, username);
        p.setString(4, password);

        int count = p.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println(String.format("%d row(s) added sucessfully", count));

        p.close();
    }

    public void readData() throws SQLException {
        String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s", tableName);
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();

        try (Statement st = con.createStatement(); 
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) {

            formatter.format("%-5s %-25s %-25s %-25s\n", "id", "name", "username", "password");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            int id = rs.getInt(1);
            String name = rs.getString(2);
            String username = rs.getString(3);
            String password = rs.getString(4);
            
            formatter.format("%-5s %-25s %-25s %-25s\n", id,name,username, password);

        }
            System.out.println(formatter);

        }
    }
    
    public void deleteData(int id) throws SQLException {
        String query = String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE id=?", tableName);
        try (PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
            p.setInt(1, id);
            
            int count = p.executeUpdate();
            
            System.out.println(String.format("%d row(s) deleted sucessfully", count));
        }
    }

    public Boolean close() throws SQLException {
        con.close();
    }
}
```

And here's the driver code:

```
import sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class BankManagementSystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in))
        {  
            SQLiteDatabase sql = new SQLiteDatabase("login_details", "(id int, name varchar(255), username varchar(255), password varchar(255))");
            
            
//           sql.showTables();
//           sql.insertData(1, "rohan", "rohan", "1234");
//           sql.deleteData(1);
            sql.readData();
            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(BankManagementSystem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

When ran with the `sql.insertData(1, "rohan", "rohan", "1234");` statement, its shows the following output:

```
1 row(s) added successfully
```

Then after running with the `sql.readData();` statement, it shows the data entry in NetBeans.
Here's the output in NetBeans:

```
id    name                      username                  password
1     rohan                     rohan                     1234
```

But when I build the JAR file (clean and build option) then run the JAR file, it doesn't show the updated database.
It just shows:

```
id    name                      username                  password
```

Please help me out! I want the data to be consistent. When I update the database from NetBeans, it should also reflect in the JAR file also.

Comment: Obviously, the database you updated through NetBeans is not the same database as the JAR. Please provide a [mre] that includes the relevant build files.

Comment: A JAR file is like a ZIP file, it is an archive of other files, but it is not trivial to (directly) change the contents of the files inside the JAR/ZIP (also not the intention of it)

Comment: I simply want to build a terminal based application. If I just run the java file, it can't find the SQLite drivers, and I have to provide a class path every time. Is there  a better way to build a terminal based application using Java, other than converting into a Jar, such that the data persistence issue is resolved. Please help me!

Comment: Your situation isn't using jpackage but you have a resource path db which means it is readonly. See [How to control SQLite 3 database files directory after installing my app (Packaged using JPackage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70163374/how-to-control-sqlite-3-database-files-directory-after-installing-my-app-packag)